# Changing Microsoft Visio default export path

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio

When I export a Microsoft Visio document to a PDF:

[image]

the default folder is always the user folder `C:\Users\Francky\Documents`, not the last folder I exported a document to:

[image]

Is there any way to change this behavior so that Microsoft Visio proposes the last folder where I exported a document instead of the user folder?

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used is always that setup in `File → Options → Advanced → File Locations → Drawings`.

[image]

[image]

I don't think there is any other option.